# .bashrc is causing git push to fail

Tags: bash, git, bashrc

I'm trying to push code using git to my remote server, but I get the error:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:
  8
```

I researched this bug and it turns out my `.bashrc` file that echos out a welcome screen is causing this error. What I would like to do is determine if this is a git push and to NOT display the welcome screen, or only display the screen when logging into SSH with no directory parameter:

```
ssh user@ssh-server.foo:/deployment/bare-git-repo
```

Here is the relevant lines in `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -e ./.doc ]
then
    cat ./.doc
    pm2 list
fi
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there’s anything specific to `git push` hooks on the server, that you could use, but you could check whether you’re outputting to a terminal:

```
if [ -t 1 ] && [ -e ./.doc ]; then
    cat ./.doc
    pm2 list
fi
```

This will deal with a number of other cases where outputting the contents `./.doc` doesn’t serve much purpose and could cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you really want to do, is prevent running things which have no business being run in a non-interactive shell from running.

A common tactic for this, is to check whether stdin is not attached to a terminal via `[[ ! -t 1 ]]`, or to check whether the bash process is not marked as interactive via `[[ $- != *i* ]]`. If one of these failure cases evaluates to true, then nothing else in your bashrc should get executed at all, and you should just return early.